# HFiles not found at path specified in hbase.rootdir property

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, mapr

I am new to bigdata. Please help me with this query.

hbase-site.xml contains:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>maprfs:///hbase</value>
  </property>
```

regionserver file content:

```
localhost
```

I have some hbase tables with data loaded and want to check their HFiles. So based on configuration I executed command:

```
hadoop fs -ls /hbase
```

But there is nothing inside this directory (blank directory). I am not getting where HFiles are stored?

Please let me know if you want more inputs.

Comment: ,try  `hadoop fs -ls  ///hbase`  ,anyother setting please show more

Comment: Thanks for reply. Command returned nothing. I mean no file or directory returned.

Comment: what about your hadoop version

Comment: some verisons should  use dfs  not fs